# Current from different batteries in parallel

Tags: current

This is a question in my schoolwork that I dont quite know how to approach, I appreciate the help!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYysjk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How can i show that ? A = 10 A?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you know that current through R2 is 10 A?

Comment: what do you know about R1?

Comment: You should start by adding numbers you can deduce to the diagram. What is the voltage after R1? You know the current through it so you can calculate the voltage drop.

Comment: I am asked to prove I1 = 10 amps, and all i know about r1 is that is it 0.1 ohms

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by simple inspection.

1. You are given that V1 supplies 25A. Therefore the voltage drop over the battery internal resistance R1 is V=IR --> 0.1 * 25 --> 2.5V.
2. The voltage across R3 is 13.5 - 2.5 = 11V
3. The current through R2 is (13 - 11)/0.2 = 10A
4. The value of R3 is R=V/I --> 11/(25 +10) = 0.314 Ohms

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 parts with 1 unknown (R) and 4 given values.
There are 3 KVL Loops and 1 KCL Nodes with 1 of 3 branch currents known.

So there with 2 unknown currents and 1 unknown component value, *there is sufficient info* to compute 2 unknowns. **R & I(R2)**

- such that I(R1) will draw 25 A in the top branch and prove that I(R2) draws 10A.

Begin with KVL ,KCL and use reduction.

KVL:

1. V load  = \$13.5~_V -25~_A*0.1~ _Ω=11  ~V \$
2. V load  = \$ 13~_V-I_2*0.2~_Ω\$
3. V load = \$I_3*R?\$

KCL:

\$25~A+I_2=I_3\$

Solve for I2 from 1. & 2. then 3.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I tried using KVL but that yielded an answer of 17 A, which isnt correct.

Comment: @Electron-Capture "which isn't correct" Yes, you made a mistake. That's a problem with mesh analysis (what Tony Stewart described) - you end up with lots of terms and it's really easy to make a mistake with the alegbra or arithmetic. I prefer to start with the easiest working method for these problems which here is the inspection method described by Jack Creasey. I suggest you study Jack's answer, make sure you understand it and can repeat the result yourself then look for the error in your mesh analysis.